# How could I store form values in an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

How would I be able to append data to an array from a form?

A list is generated according to the data found in the database. Each row has a part number and a QTY text field for the user to edit:

```
+--------+----------+
| Part # | QTY      |
+--------+----------+
| 123    | [0]      |
+--------+----------+
| 124    | [2]      |
+--------+----------+
| 125    | [15]     |
+--------+----------+
|        | [Submit] |
+--------+----------+
```

The logic I have so far is:

```
If QTY = 0 { 
ignore 
} else {
append values to array object and store array under "parts" session
}
```

An issue I'm running into is when the form is submitted, it grabs the last part and qty value in the form. I need to somehow make each row unique for the form and input that form data into array.

I plan on after the user adds all the parts and qtys to the array, the array is then submitted into a database.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

### EDIT:

Grabs the part number and submits the qty value via the form.

```
<input type="text" name="item['.$row['Part'].'][qty]" size="2" value="0"/>
```

So it would look like this:

```
123 => 0, 124 => 2, 125 => 15
```

And if value in form is set, map the array. I also used the `array_filter()` function to get rid of the 0 qty parts:

```
function show_Names($e)
    {
        return "$e[qty]";
    }
        if(isset($_POST['item'])) {
        $c = array_filter(array_map("show_Names", $_POST['item']));
    }
```

And stored it in a session this way. If nothing is set so far, set a new session. If something is set, then just add onto the array:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['parts'])) {             
        if(isset($c)) {
        $_SESSION['parts']=$_SESSION['parts']+$c;
        }
    } else {
        if(isset($c)) {
        $_SESSION['parts']=$c;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone else tackling a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By naming the fields like:

```
<input type="text" name="item[0][name]" />
<input type="text" name="item[0][email]" />

<input type="text" name="item[1][name]" />
<input type="text" name="item[1][email]" />

<input type="text" name="item[2][name]" />
<input type="text" name="item[2][email]" />
```

And php script:

```
function show_Names($e)
{
  return "The name is $e[name] and email is $e[email], thank you";
}

$c = array_map("show_Names", $_POST['item']);
print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add square brackets to your textbox name attribute for example:

```
<input type="text" name="part[]" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" />

<input type="text" name="part[]" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" />

<input type="text" name="part[]" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" />
```

You will then have all part no &  qty into $_POST['part'] and $_POST['qty']

Comment: ... and you can continue to check if qty = 0 by doing `array_sum()` on that array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php.